# Retrofit GET request with a parameter

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I make a call to an api using Retrofit GET request. This GET request requires a parameter. The API works perfectly when i use POSTMAN for testing but when i try to use the API call below it returns

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
@GET("/api/account/*******")
Call<ResetPassword> requestPasswordResetToken(@Query("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
```

And the code how i make that request in my activity.

```
public void requestPasswordResetToken(String phoneNumber) {

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getClient("");
    APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "Loading your information...", false, false);
    loading.setCancelable(true);
    loading.show();

    mAPIService.requestPasswordResetToken(phoneNumber).enqueue(new Callback<ResetPassword>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResetPassword> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if(response.isSuccess()) {
                String loginSuccess = response.body().getSuccess();
                String message = response.body().getMessage();
                if (loginSuccess.equals("true")) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    showSnackMessage(message);

                }else {
                    Log.e("loginError", message);
                    Toast.makeText(RequestPasswordResetActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("ResetPasswordError", throwable.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(RequestPasswordResetActivity.this, "Unable to Login, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loading.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

the screenshot of the what the API expects. The field names are correct.

[image: This is what the API expects.]

Comment: Log your API Calls with `com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor` and check

Comment: @SivakumarS it is already logged and this is my response D/OkHttp: {
D/OkHttp:   "total": 0,
D/OkHttp:   "data": null,
D/OkHttp:   "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
D/OkHttp:   "success": false
D/OkHttp: }

Answer (score 2):

Your codes looks fine. Do you check the result format of the api you are working on. And also ResetPassword class properties (variable names and types) must be same with response of the api. (be careful about upper case or lower case letters).

And also try this format request

```
  @GET("methodName/{PARAMETER}")
Call<Object> getData(
        @Path("telephoneNumber") String telephoneNumber
);
```

Comment: i have updated my answer with a screenshot of the variable name and data type the API expects.

Comment: The api gives you the result. i mean the response. json object atributes must be same name with your special class.

Comment: from your answer i tried this but did not workout @GET("/api/account/******/{phoneNumber}")
    Call<ResetPassword> requestPasswordResetToken(
            @Path("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber
    );

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are calling correct method, you seem to call `requestPasswordResetToken` but you are showing `resendVerification` inside your interface.

Comment: I have edited the question with the right implementation but that is not the problem..problem still persists.

Comment: @LendingSquare Check your retrofit initialization, and api logs, try to find the details of the failure.