# Retrofit to get request using parameter

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I would like to make a get through retrofit using the parameter via url.

```
Base Url = .../.../...?t=id
```

"t" here is my parameter.

Output json data as follows:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "names":[
     "xxxxxx",
     "yyyyyy"
  ]

}
```

How can I do it? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit GET request with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745066/retrofit-get-request-with-a-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

You should declare interface

```
public interface RestInterface {

    @GET("/fixed_url/{path_param1}_{path_param2}?")
    Result doGetRequest(@Path("path_param1") String from,
                                        @Path("path_param2") String to,
                                        @Query("get_param1") String getParam1,
                                        @Query("get_param2") String getParam2);
}
```

Build retrofit object instance

```
Retrofit rtft = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://your_server_url:port")
                .build();
```

After that you can get instance of the interface and make HTTP REST call

```
rtft.create(RestInterface.class).doGetSuggestions(....);
```